# Windows installer 'send to' menu item for all users

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, installation

I use the visual studio application installer to deploy my application on the end users machine. 
In the setup project I need to add a shortcut to the application exe file in the user's 'send to' menu items.

Now the thing is I need this 'send to' shortcut to be installed for all users, not only for the user
who runs the installer (which is the admin). I can find no way to do this for all users in the setup project.

Anyone an idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to manually copy the shortcut in Send To folder of each user profile folder. You can try using a custom action for this.

From my knowledge Windows doesn't support per-machine "Send To" shortcuts.